# Why does this create action infinite loop when using the ajax helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Why does this `create` action infinite loop when using the ajax helper?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @user = User.new
        @users = User.all
    end
    def create
        user_params = params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
        @user = User.create!(user_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            create.html {redirect_to users_path}
            create.js
        end
    end
end
```

The above results in an infinite loop of users being created. Additionally, the create.js.erb is never run, so I am assuming the post request is just being re-sent over and over.

When I remove the `respond_to` block, replace it with a simple redirect, and remove `remote: true` from the form, everything works fine.

The form (views/users/index.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do |form| %>
    <%= form.email_field :email, placeholder: "email" %>
    <%= form.password_field :password, placeholder: "password" %>
    <%= form.submit "Create User" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling create in a method called create without a break to jump aout of the loop:

The correct code for your respond_to must be:

```
def create
    user_params = params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
    @user = User.create!(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to users_path}
        format.js
    end
end
```